# Kubectl on AKS returned error error: the server doesn't have a resource type ""

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks

I setup a test deployment, deployed it just fine with kubectl apply -f testdeployment.yml

The yaml file was:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.14.2
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx-service
  labels:
     app: nginx
spec:
  selector:
    app: nginx
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 80
  type: LoadBalancer
```

I should be able to clean this all up with:
kubectl delete -f testdeployment.yml

But, much to my amazement, it returned the error:   error: the server doesn't have a resource type ""

I'm sure this is due to some weird thing in YAML, where there is a space, or lack of a space, or a blank line or something, but why can it parse it and apply it just fine, but then can't reverse it??

The fact that I can apply this, and not un-apply it, implies there is a bug in AKS
I get the same error if I copy just the top part, or just the bottom part and save that in a file and attempt a delete -f testdeployment1.yml

Which implies that both of them have the same problem, or Kubernetes is just broken and I need to delete the entire service and recreate it...  (I also noticed a spike on the VM, went from $4 charge for first day to $16 for 2nd day, which makes this $496/month to have one nginx server running, which, off the top of my head is a hard NO... I have $50/month credit on this account, so I can test with this for 3 days each month?  (Included here because that could be a clue..)

(Oh, I had replicas as 2 when I ran this the first time, no other changes to the file)
Dropped it to 0 today in a hope to 'delete' this as much as possible

Comment: You can get more detailed information on what's going on with `kubectl delete -f testdeployment.yaml -v=6`. There might be a lot of text, so if you could add any suspicious information to your question, it might make troubleshooting easier.

Answer (score 0):

i tested your test-deployment and it is working fine for me on an AKS:

```
kubectl apply -f testdeployment.yml
deployment.apps/nginx created
service/nginx-service created
---
kubectl delete -f testdeployment.yml
deployment.apps "nginx" deleted
service "nginx-service" deleted
```

Is your kubectl version up-to date? An easy work-around is to just delete the namespace you deployed this in : `kubectl delete ns testdeplyoment`

AKS runs the default nodepool on a Virtual Machine Scaling Set so based on the choice of the node count and the node size your budget will be affected. Managed Kubernetes is not cheap and with 50$ per month you should better check out [ACI](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/container-instances/#overview) or [ACA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-apps/overview) to run just a nginx container.

Comment: I presume it is up to date, I'm running it on the console in Azure...

Comment: I'm actually trying to do tests for eventually setting up AKS for a client,   I'm using the Nginx image because it gives me a web page that I can verify that connecting to it via the load balancer is working.  I was instructed to set this up via my Visual Studio subscription account, and I've noticed that the selecting the cost optimized configuration defaults to 3 nodes running at the $86 tier.   This is optimized to cost you a lot.  If you instead change the machine the nodes are running on to the $36 VM, and select 1 node instead, It appears you can remove about $172/month from your bill!